# Yii nested dropDownList with optiongroup

Tags: yii

i started to learn yii a few days ago and now i'm stuck with the following problem for hours...

I want to generate a dropDownList like

```
<div class="cars-select">
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('Cars', 'car_id', array(
        'Mazda'=>array(
            'mazda-rx7'=>'RX7',
            'mazda-rx5'=>'RX5',
        ),
        'Volvo'=>array(
            'volvo-b9tl'=>'B9TL',
            'volvo-l90e-radlader'=>'L90E Radlader',
        ),
    )); ?>
</div>
```

But i get the data from the Database with following table-structure:

```
Table Studycourse: 
id, coursename, extension_of

1, Law, 0
2, Economics, 0
3, Business Law, 1
4, Macro Economics, 2
```

My DropDownList without option group is working:

```
$courseExt = Studycourse::model()->findAll("extension_of IS NOT NULL", array('order' => 'id'));
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'studycourse_id', GxHtml::listDataEx($courseExt));
```

But how can i populate a dropdownlist with option groups?

It should generate the following html:

```
<select name="studycourse" id="course">
        <optgroup label="Law">
            <option value="law-business">Business Law</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Economics">
            <option value="economics-macro">Macro Economics</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://bit.ly/KV5Az7)

Comment: ok, i forgot to mention that i want to generate the dropdownlist in views/profile.php. I have an additional table tbl_profile (user_id, name, studycourse_id) and there is a reference to table studycourse. The $model-object in views/profile is the profiles

Comment: $model in views/profile is the profiles-object. How can i use the studycourse-modelobject in profile view?

Comment: My answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806433/yii-active-dropdownlist-with-optgroup/33510417#33510417

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category Table:
id   name          grp
1    Ms Office     Software
2    Photo shop    Software
3    C++           Programming
4    Java          Programming
5    PHP           Programming

$category = CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name','grp');

echo CHtml::dropDownList('location', '', $location);

Comment: I would extend your answer with some explanations and a bit more formatting :-)