# Yii active dropdownlist with optgroup

Tags: php, yii, drop-down-menu

I try to create dropdown-list with Yii, using listData and activeDropDownList.

I use the examples found on the web, but it refuses to create the optgroups for me.

```
$data = CHtml::listData(MyModel::model()->getEntries(0), 'id', 'text', 'group');
```

Generates an array as expected:

```
Array([group1] => Array([10]=>FirstEntry, [20]=>SecondEntry),
 [group2]=>Array([30]=>firstEntryGroup2, [40]=>firstEntryGroup2))
```

And so on. So it's an associative array filled with sub-arrays...

But when I use

```
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'dropdownName', $data);
```

All I get is a flat dropdown without the optgroups. Just the entries from the sub-arrays...

Yii 1.1.6 (I read something about safe-attributes and tried to implement it, but with no success...

Comment: Is `$data` being changed/overwritten anywhere before being used in the dropDownList?

Comment: no, definitely not... I get the right content, it's just the group that's missing (a.k.a. the keys of the main array)

Comment: That is really weird behaviour then. What version of Yii are you using? You could also look at the source code for [CHtml::listOptions()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listOptions-detail) for further debugging.

Comment: I'm using 1.1.6 - I actually checked all the docs and as far as I'm concerned, everything's right... I'll check the docs for listOptions again, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old answer below is incorrect. Sorry. You create optgroups using a 'group' attribute in your drop down data array.

`array(
    array('id'=>256,'text'=>'TV','group'=>'Electrical'),
    array('id'=>257,'text'=>'Radio','group'=>'Electrical'),
);`

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6903-how-can-i-generate-a-select-list-with-optgroup/

Old answer:

There is a great gist here that shows how do create what you're after: https://gist.github.com/StandardNerd/2909111

`<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('Cars', 'car_id', array(
        'Mazda'=>array(
            'mazda-rx7'=>'RX7',
            'mazda-rx5'=>'RX5',
        ),
        'Volvo'=>array(
            'volvo-b9tl'=>'B9TL',
            'volvo-l90e-radlader'=>'L90E Radlader',
        ),
    )); ?>`

You're currently using an activeDropDownList which should only be different because you add your $model variable instead of 'Cars' and tweak the function

Answer (score -1):

One of solutions is anonymous function.

```
$data = CHtml::listData(
    MyModel::model()->getEntries(0),
    'id',
    'text',
    function(MyModel $aMyModelInstance){
        return $aMyModelInstance->getLocalizedGroupNameForThisInstance();
 });
```